# Keys enumeration C#, AltKey

Tags: c#, keyboard, user-input

The three modifier keys are Control, Alt and Shift.
In the keys enumeration, there are Control and ControlKey, Shift and ShiftKey and Alt, but AltKey is missing.

Keys.ControlKey refers to the actual Ctrl key while Keys.Control refers to the control modification.
Similarly,Keys.ShiftKey refers to the actual Shift key while Keys.Shift refers to the shift modification.

What about the actual Alt key?
It can be pressed by itself and the corresponding element in the Keys enumeration should be Keys.AltKey!

**Can you please explain the lack of the vlaue Keys.AltKey in the Keys enumeration?**

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the real key (not modifier) enumeration value for Alt key is `Keys.Menu` with the value of `18`. That's just a naming convention. They decided to use the `Alt` name just for the modifer, and `Menu` for the non-modifier. Interestingly, the documentation for the `Keys.Menu` says "**The ALT key**". We also have `Keys.LMenu` and `Keys.RMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess I'd say that the lack of the Alt key is due to the fact that in WinForms development, the paradigm used for setting shortcut keys is to prefix a letter with the `&` character, e.g., `E&xit`. When the application is run, this is automatically set up as a shortcut command Alt+X. Most windows shortcut keys are set up this way in development pretty much removing any reason why you'd want to detect it in code - or at least a KeyDown event. That said, I personally would have expected the Alt key to be available.